# Import CSV/Excel file data into 2 tables (sql server 2012) using Fluent Nhibernate c#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Hi,
I've a csv/excel file and want to insert the data in the excel/csv file into 2 tables of my sql server database using C# Fluent `Nhibernate` repository pattern.

My 2 tables are :

```
table1 (Id, FieldName)
table2 (Id, table1Id, Name, ...)
```

table1's primary key is acting as foreign key in table2.

entire data to insert in these 2 tables is available in single excel/csv file. So, Is it possible to do this process using **C# Fluent Nhibernate**? if so, any one please give me an idea?

Thanks,
sampath

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible.  Here is a very rudimentary example of how you would do this.

pseudo code:

#### Entities

```
class table1
{
    int id;
    List<table2> table2s;
}

class table2
{
    int id;
    table1 instance;
    string name;
}
```

#### Mappings

```
public class table1Map: ClassMap<table1>
{
  public table1Map()
  {
    Table("table1");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasMany(x => x.table2s).Cascade.All();
  }
}

public class table2Map: ClassMap<table2>
{
  public table2Map()
  {
    Table("table2");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.instance);
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```
using (var session = new  Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession())  
{  
    table1 t1 = new table1();
    t1.table2s.Add(new table2());

    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())  
    {  
        session.Save(t1);
        transaction.Commit();  
    }  
}
```